# Is this valid node.js require? "const { EXAMPLE.SOMETHING } = require ('example')"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I was looking using a package today that used the following syntax in the documentation:

`const { BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY } = require ('@contentful/rich-text-types')`

When I tried it in my project I got a "unexpected token '.'" error, so I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or whether the author just made a mistake.

Is this a valid require?

I've not seen requires written like this before, so I tried searching "node dot require" and some other possible keywords (wasn't sure what to call it), but nothing turned up.

**MORE EXAMPLES**

I see Contentful using this syntax in multiple places, so it doesn't seem like it could be just a mistake.

https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-html-renderer

https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-contentful-richtext

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a [valid ES6 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so it probably is an error from the documentation.

They probably wanted to import `BLOCKS` and then use `BLOCKS.something`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are talking about this documentation : https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/getting-started-with-rich-text-field-type/#use-cases-around-rendering-the-api-response

Looking at the code i'd say that they made a mistake using :

`import { BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';`

instead of

`import { BLOCKS } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';`

because if you take a look just a bit further in the code you can see : `BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH` they are using `BLOCKS` just like if they imported it

Comment: That's what I thought, but I see the same syntax in multiple places for multiple packages. Doesn't seem like they would make a mistake that many times. See: https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-html-renderer

```
import { BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH, MARKS.BOLD } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';
import { documentToHtmlString } from '@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer';
```

Comment: Yep it's kinda weird, i never seen this import syntax and i doubt that would works. they are maybe using a automatic process to generate documentation which is subject to a bug. Try to open an issue on their github.

Answer (score 0):

I believe OP is referring to Contentful's Javascript SDK docs. Specifically the chunk referenced at https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/rendering-contentful-rich-text-with-javascript/

For your reference:

```
import * as contentful from 'contentful';
import { documentToHtmlString } from '@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer'; // <--- this was a problem for me

const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: '<space_id>',
  environment: '<environment_id>', // defaults to 'master' if not set
  accessToken: '<content_delivery_api_key>'
});

client.getEntry('<entry_id>'); // asynchronous, returns promise

...

 client
        .getEntry('<entry_id>')
        .then(entry => {
          const rawRichTextField = entry.fields.body;
          return documentToHtmlString(rawRichTextField);
        })
        .then(renderedHtml => {
          // do something with html, like write to a file
          console.log(renderedHtml);
          document.getElementById('rich-text-body').innerHTML = renderedHtml;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Running the above import chunk in my Node app (version 11.15.0) I was getting an error on import syntax.

However, the following import syntax worked for me:

```
const documentToHtmlString = require("@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer").documentToHtmlString

const htmlString = documentToHtmlString(rawRichTextField)

console.log(htmlString)
```